# Why my app is crash when search view is used?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i am new to android i do a project and load it on in play store by disabling minifyEnabled false it work fine when i download and run but when i upload the apk by enabling minifyEnabled true the the app crash by showing following error

```
04-05 15:33:10.795 1524-1524/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.asiczen.azlock.GuestListActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3320)
    at android.support.v4.app.i.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.view.i.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.f$a.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.k.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.k.f(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.k$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: Share few code for better understand cause of error

Comment: MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.guest_list_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);

Answer (score 0):

Had this error too. Solved by adding the following to your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: you can create that file in the root level project and make sure its referenced in your build.gradle like `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`. Or do you have a similar file where you store your custom proguard configuration?